# Error only when running whole block of code

Tags: r, syntax-error

I have code that came with a dataset that I downloaded.  This code is supposed to convert factor variables to numeric.  When I run each line individually, it works fine, but if I try to highlight a whole section, then I get the following error:

> Error: unexpected input in ...

It gives me this error for every line of code, but again if I run each line individually, then it works fine.  I've never run into this before.  What's going on??  Thanks!

Here's the code that I'm trying to run:

```
library(prettyR)
lbls <- sort(levels(DF$myVar))
lbls <- (sub("^\\([0-9]+\\) +(.+$)", "\\1", lbls))
DF$myVar <- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", DF$myVar))
DF$myVar <- add.value.labels(DF$myVar, lbls)
```

And here is the output with the errors:

```
> library(prettyR)
"rror: unexpected input in "library(prettyR)
> lbls <- sort(levels(DF$myVar))
"rror: unexpected input in "lbls <- sort(levels(DF$myVar))
> lbls <- (sub("^\\([0-9]+\\) +(.+$)", "\\1", lbls))
"rror: unexpected input in "lbls <- (sub("^\\([0-9]+\\) +(.+$)", "\\1", lbls))
> surv.df$myVar <- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", DF$myVar))
"rror: unexpected input in "DF$myVar <- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1",DF$myVar))
> surv.df$BATTLEGROUND <- add.value.labels(DF$myVar, lbls)
Error in add.value.labels(surv.df$myVar, lbls) : 
object 'lbls' not found
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the factor levels?  That doesn't seem to matter to do that. It's hard to tell without some data to test it on. The error actually says exactly `Error: unexpected input in ...`? Please post the result of `dput(head(DF))`

Comment: And I'm not sure why the factor levels are sorted.  This is just code that came with the dataset, and it seems to work fine except when I try to run multiple lines at once.  It's not a major problem because I can run each line separately, but it just seems strange to me that it's having this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out the issue  (actually someone told me what the problem was)

The code was downloaded as a .R file and must have been written using a text editor with non-standard "new line" coding.  So I just copied the code to a text editor, did replace all to switch "\n" to 
"#####".  Then I used replace all again to switch back to new-lines and copied it back into R studio.

And everything works!

Comment: I had a similar problem with the "power" character ^. I cut-pasted it into another editor, then back into RStudio after a restart and that removed the problem: my ^ character is obtained, on my keyboard, by pressing a deadkey twice, so probably some invisible character is somehow appended to it and, similar to the invisble newline character, was interfering. (Note however that I have used the ^ character a zillion times before without problems, so there is a part of mystery remaining).