# Why does this work in the R console but not in a function

Tags: r

When I enter this code directly into the R console it works perfectly.

```
for(i in files) df<-rbind(df,read.csv(paste(directory,i,sep="/")))
```

If I nest the above code in the below function it throws an

> Unexpected input Error

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id){ 
    files <- list.files(directory) 
    df <- data.frame() 
    newdf <- data.frame() 
    for(i in files){
        df <-rbind(df,read.csv(paste(directory,i,sep="/")))
    }
    for(j in id){
        newdf <- rbind(df[which(df$ID==j),])
    }
    return(mean(na.omit(newdf[,pollutant]))) 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `If I include it in a function`? What is the function? `pollutantmean`? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644789/r-studio-console-error-message).

Comment: Yes. That's it Pascal.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is trying things in the console; setting variables, writing statements, etc. then using the R Studio text editor to incorporate them into a function.  In the console it all works fine, when I paste it into the function then paste the whole function back into the console it throws the error.

Comment: It currently looks like this:

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Comment: pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id){
  files <- list.files(directory)
  df <- data.frame()
  newdf <- data.frame()
  
  for(i in files) df<-rbind(df,read.csv(paste(directory,i,sep="/")))     
    for(j in id) newdf<-rbind(df[which(df$ID==j),])
  
  return(mean(na.omit(newdf[,pollutant])))
 }

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this and still trying to figure out how to make code look like code in the comments.

Comment: @Tomfoolery you should put the comment into the question.  I just did if for you.

Comment: @TomFoolery  For a single line or isolated piece of code, insert it inside backticks. For a block, use a 4-space indent.

Comment: Thanks Pascal and Jacob.

Comment: i think you should try figuring out exactly what line it errors out. Then try piecing apart whats making it error. does it not loop through at all? does it error out at the first attempt to read.csv? provide more details since you don't have a replicable example

Answer (score 0):

Another post on stackoverflow suggests it is caused by copy-pasting and newline character mismatch

[Error only when running whole block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452065/error-only-when-running-whole-block-of-code)

However, I wonder if here  it is caused by wrong file path. Maybe the *directory* variable you are passing already ends is "/" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is ok if you call it right. This works for me:

```
directory <- "~/Documents/temp/csv/"

pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id) {
  files <- list.files(directory) 
  df <- data.frame()
  newdf <- data.frame()
  for(i in files) {
    df <-rbind(df,read.csv(paste(directory,i,sep="/")))
  }
  for(j in id){
    newdf <- rbind(df[which(df$ID==j),])
  }
  return(mean(na.omit(newdf[,pollutant]))) 
}

pollutantmean(directory, 'val', c('x'))
[1] 2.5
```

for data that looks like this:

```
ID,val
x,1
y,2
z,3
```

and this:

```
ID,val
x,4
w,2
```